# In-page bookmark link issue

Tags: html, anchor

Many pages on sites I run have localised links in the form of `http://www.site.co.uk/index.php#calendar`. These work as expected - taking the browser to the `calendar` part of the web page `index.php` in IE and Chrome, however the newer versions of Firefox seem to have an issue in that they are *only displaying the chosen id area on the page*.

For example; I have a page with the following HTML content (assume name is **index.php** ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.site.co.uk/avail/index.php" >

    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <script src="/includes/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- STYLE SHEETS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/sitewide.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/control.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<nav>...</nav>
<h1>A Heading</h1>
<section>    
    <h2>Heading H2 one</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <p>Bulking text, etc etc etc.</p>
    </section>  
<section>
    <h2><a id='text1'></a>Section 2</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <p>Bulking text, etc etc etc.</p>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when the page is visited at `index.php` then the whole page - 2 headers and 6 paragraph blocks - are displayed. When the page is visited with `index.php#text1` *only the second header and paragraph blocks are displayed on Firefox*.

I have noticed this across several different sites on HTML5. Some points:

- The rendering of the page only begins at the DOM level the id tag occurs. such as if the id tag occurs in a `<section>` then only that section and all parent elements are displayed.
- This is not effected by the deprecated anchor `name` attribute.
- This is not effected by where or in what element the id tag is positioned.
- This effect does not seem to be influenced by CSS/JS base stylers such as **normalize.css** or **bootstrap**. There is a minor difference in  **modernizer** where the page loads with the problem but then refreshing the page displays the whole page *but does not focus the browser window on the id tag area*.
- When viewing the site through **Firebug** the entire site source code is present (but is not displayed), firebug also does not seem to show any `display:none;` that I have found.
- My pages are W3C HTML5 valid according to the Nu-HTML checker linked from W3C validator.

So, to conclude:

After reading this can you tell me how to side step or even solve this issue? Or if there is some syntax mistake I've made that's causing this issue, What can I do to correct this behaviour?

Finally: A test page featuring the problem as it presents itself to me can be found here on a test site page: http://www.walberswick.org.uk/index.php

Comment: I originally wrote this question yesterday and found the Chrome worked ok with this, however I am now finding the same issue on Chrome, and safari so I'm sure my syntax could be wrong , but not sure how?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your css. On click you get some weird overflow bug in all browsers. I played for awhile with it and after changing these:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px)
.leftSideText {
    padding: 2px 2px 2500px 2px;
    margin-bottom: -2500px;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px)
.imgSideText {
    padding: 1px 1px 2500px 1px;
    margin-bottom: -2500px;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
}
```

to these:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px)
.leftSideText {
    padding: 2px 2px 2500px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px)
.imgSideText {
    padding: 1px 1px 2500px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

all worked fine.

A thing to note. Use `display: property` instead of `float: property` or flexbox. Make sure to have only one `main` element per page and include it's `role="main"`.

Comment: Do you think the "overflow" is related to the `2500px` sizing? this was something I found from SO to make the height of the right hand column always be minimum the same height as the left side column.

Comment: And how did you discover the CSS overflow bug? My cursory debugging I couldn't find anything telling me of issues (such as Friebug), Cheers.

Comment: That margin property leaded me to it, but it didn't caused the problem. The margin is a fully valid like that. When you have a lot of work and experience with CSS building lots of layouts, you can easely spot such things. The `float` was causing an `overflow`. More on floats here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I have removed the big value padding/margin and that has made things work as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!